# Evaluating Compton scattering cross-section

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In deriving the cross-section of Compton scattering, we require to perform the polarization sum $$\sum\epsilon_{\mu}\epsilon_{\nu}\sum\epsilon_{\alpha}\epsilon_{\beta}$$ using the identity $\sum\epsilon_{\mu}\epsilon_{\nu}=-g_{\mu\nu}$. In Peskin and Schoeder, they have substituted $g_{\mu\nu}g_{\alpha\beta}=1$, in equation 5.81. But   if I understand it correct, none of its indices are contracted. And therefore $g_{\mu\nu}g_{\alpha\beta}$ is a covariant tensor of rank-4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They haven't done that. In the part just above 5.81 you'll see that there are gamma matricies with upper $\mu,\nu,\rho,\sigma$ indices.

Then in 5.81 the term $g_{\mu\rho}g_{\nu\sigma}$ has been absorbed into the things they call I, II, III, IV.

If you look down at the equation under 5.81 you'll see there are no longer any upper $\sigma$ or $\rho$ indices, but terms with upper $\mu,\nu$ and terms with lower $\mu,\nu$. So they just contracted the gamma matricies with upper $\sigma,\rho$ indices with the metric tensors $g_{\mu\rho}g_{\nu\sigma}$.